# System.OutOfMemoryException with PLINQ

Tags: out-of-memory, plinq

I am trying to update a standard LINQ query to use PLINQ.  The standard query looks like this:

```
var query = (from doc in this.ownershipRepository.GetDocuments()
     let queryStateCode = this.currentQuery.StateCode
         let queryCountyCode = this.currentQuery.CountyCode
         where queryStateCode != null ? doc.StateCode == queryStateCode : true &&
         queryCountyCode != null ? doc.CountyCode == queryCountyCode : true
         orderby doc.Owner
     select doc)
     .Take(QUERY_RESULTS_SIZE);
```

The .GetDocuments() method in the repository is simply this:

```
public class OwnershipRepository : IDisposable
{
    private OwnershipEntities context;

...


public IQueryable<Document> GetDocuments()
    {
        return this.context.Documents;
    }

...
}
```

And this works just fine.  I tried to leverage the query with PLINQ as follows:

```
var query = (from doc in this.ownershipRepository.GetDocuments().AsParallel()
     let queryStateCode = this.currentQuery.StateCode
     let queryCountyCode = this.currentQuery.CountyCode
         where queryStateCode != null ? doc.StateCode == queryStateCode : true &&
     queryCountyCode != null ? doc.CountyCode == queryCountyCode : true
     orderby doc.Owner
     select doc)
     .AsSequential()
     .Take(QUERY_RESULTS_SIZE);
```

But this throws a System.OutOfMemoryException.  I am testing this on a machine with the following specs:

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 860 @ 2.80GHz 2.79 GHz / 4 GB memory

Is there something I need to be doing to optimize this query so it doesn't cause out of memory problems?

Answer (score 1):

Making query parallel means to split it on some stage and then merge it back again.
You are splitting at the beginning. This seems to be correct. Than you filter and sort splitted sequences. These need be kept in mem and merged back. My suggestion is to sort at the end after merging.

```
var query = (from doc in this.ownershipRepository.GetDocuments().AsParallel()
     let queryStateCode = this.currentQuery.StateCode
     let queryCountyCode = this.currentQuery.CountyCode
         where queryStateCode != null ? doc.StateCode == queryStateCode : true &&
     queryCountyCode != null ? doc.CountyCode == queryCountyCode : true
     select doc);

var result = query.AsSequential().OrderBy(doc=>doc.Owner).Take(QUERY_RESULTS_SIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I changed my query as you suggested, but I am still getting an OutOfMemoryException.  It happens when initializing a List<string> property on one of the entities.  I have a subclass of EntityObject called StatefulEntityObject where I set some properties that are used to manage the state of the entities during a business transaction.  I know that there are state management features in the ObjectContext, but this has some custom stuff that I use to set the view state of the rows in the grid that the entities are attached to.

Comment: I think that having this subclass is what is causing my woes.  I will keep in mind your suggestion for future PLINQ implementations when I'm not using my own burdensome subclass.